# Jupyter: How do I recall and edit the previous "In:" text?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In a command line Python session I can press Control-P to retrieve the previously entered line edit it.

How can I perform a similar operation in Jupyter, i.e. carry forward the contents of the previous "In:" block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Jupyter doesn't have such a feature out of the box, although, you could write your own custom keyboard shortcut using CodeMirror API: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

First you need to create your own `custom.js` file:
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html#custom.js

You could try something like this (depending on what you're expecting to get):

```js
CodeMirror.keyMap.pcDefault["Ctrl-P"] = function(cm) {

    var selected = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
    if (!Jupyter.notebook.get_prev_cell(selected)) {
        // This is the first cell
        return;
    }

    Jupyter.notebook.select_prev();
    Jupyter.notebook.copy_cell();
    Jupyter.notebook.select_next();
    Jupyter.notebook.paste_cell_replace();
    Jupyter.notebook.handle_edit_mode(selected);

}
```

This will copy the contents of the cell above and insert it into the currently selected cell. You could replace `paste_cell_replace()` method with `paste_cell_above()` to create a new cell instead of replacing the contents of the currently selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a lame solution, but you can just copy the cell, right? Press `Esc`, select the cell (mostly likely the previous one, thus press `Up`) and press `c` and `v`.

Comment: No maybe about this one, I fear :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript code:

```
%%js
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-l', {
    help : 'Insert Input from Above',
    help_index : 'zz',
    handler: function(env) {
        var cm=env.notebook.get_selected_cell().code_mirror;
        cm.doc.replaceSelection(Jupyter.notebook.get_cell(Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_index()-1).get_text());
        cm.execCommand('goLineEnd');
        return false;
    }}
);
```

More explanation in  https://web.archive.org/web/20200904003015/https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jupyter-notebook-insert-output-from-above-more-wang-frank