# IPython in Jupyter notebook: recall previous command

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

In the Unix shell, you press up-arrow to recall previous command. With Jupyter, so far I could only hack to achieve this behaviour with copy-and-paste through C and Shift-V shortcut, or go into previous cell and run it again, which is cumbersome.

Is there a standard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any shortcuts for copying contents of any old cell and pasting in another, nor am I able to find a reason not to reuse the cell itself than just the code in it. Some useful shortcuts are:

<kbd>⌘/Ctrl+M P</kbd>: Previous cell

<kbd>⌘/Ctrl+Shift+G</kbd>: Global find previous

These ca be found in preferences. You can also set shortcut for 'Copy to scratch cell' which is not set by default (at least for me).

**EDIT**

Just found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315384/10689064

Comment: Thanks. On mac with py3.7 homebrew, I can't get your commands to work, but I found the moderator's link helpful. `%recall` workds though still not ideal.